# running function during post save and adding variable to post meta

Tags: post-meta

I'm creating a page that is pulling info from Vimeo using oEmbed. Everything works fine but the multiple calls to vimeo are causing page load issues (obviously).

I was wondering if it would be possible to make the same oEmbed call when the post is being created/saved, then populating various post meta variables with the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, most definitely. Take this skeleton code below as a base for a function that would do what you want, and place it in your functions.php:

```
function your_vimeo_meta_function ($post_id) {

    // some verifications first
    if ( $post_id == null || empty($_POST) )
        return;

    if ( !isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) || $_POST['post_type']!='post' )  
        return; 

    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        $post_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );

    global $post;  
    if ( empty( $post ) )
        $post = get_post($post_id);

    /* 
     * do your vimeo stuff here 
     */

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'your_vimeo_key_name', $your_vimeo_value);
    // if this key doesn't exist, it will be created. If it exists, it will be updated
}
add_action('save_post', 'your_vimeo_meta_function', 12 );
```

Comment: Awesome. This works, I'm able to use it to populate the post meta key with arbitrary data. Unfortunately, for some reason, it wont accept me saving data directly from the XML. I'll need to look into that as I'm sure it's an unrelated problem.